# Powershell XML node edit when multiple nodes of same name

Tags: xml, powershell, xml-parsing

I have an XML file with the following structure:

```
<ReportParameters>
<Parameter id="mxrNZh/4cyLB/qExTbTjCg==" subreportfilter="True">
<Name>Absence Start Date</Name>
<Type>DateRange</Type>
<PromptText>Absence Start Date is between</PromptText>
<Values>
<DateRange>
<Start>2022-04-21T13:45:35</Start>
<End>2023-04-21T13:45:35</End>
</DateRange>
</Values>
</Parameter>
<Parameter id="mxrNZh/4cyLB/qExTbTjCg==" subreportfilter="True">
<Name>Absence Start Date</Name>
<Type>DateRange</Type>
<PromptText>Absence Start Date is between</PromptText>
<Values>
<DateRange>
<Start>2022-04-21T13:43:01</Start>
<End>2023-04-21T13:43:01</End>
</DateRange>
</Values>
</Parameter>
<Parameter id="mxrNZh/4cyLB/qExTbTjCg==" subreportfilter="True">
<Name>Absence Start Date</Name>
<Type>DateRange</Type>
<PromptText>Absence Start Date is between</PromptText>
<Values>
<DateRange>
<Start>2022-04-21T11:51:40</Start>
<End>2023-04-21T11:51:40</End>
</DateRange>
</Values>
</Parameter>
<Parameter id="mxrNZh/4cyLB/qExTbTjCg==" subreportfilter="True">
<Name>Absence Start Date</Name>
<Type>DateRange</Type>
<PromptText>Absence Start Date is between</PromptText>
<Values>
<DateRange>
<Start>2022-04-21T13:11:49</Start>
<End>2023-04-21T13:11:49</End>
</DateRange>
</Values>
</Parameter>
</ReportParameters>
```

When I try

```
$xmldocument = [xml](Get-Content "params.xml")
$xmldocument.reportparameters.parameter.values.DateRange.start = (Get-Date).AddYears(-2).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss")
```

I get the error that says property start is not found. When I remove the three duplicate nodes at the end of the file so only a single one remains, it works.

In order for the program I'm running to work, it needs all 4 nodes. I'm just trying to change the date (to the same date) of each one. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Member-Access enumeration only works for getting values, not setting them. See [**about_Member-Access_Enumeration**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_member-access_enumeration?view=powershell-7.2).

> You can use the member-access operator to get the values of a property on items in a collection but you can't use it to set them directly. For more information, see [about_Arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-7.2#member-access-enumeration).

You need to loop over each object to update their property values:

```bash
$xmldocument.reportparameters.parameter.values.DateRange |
    ForEach-Object { $_.start = (Get-Date).AddYears(-2).ToString('yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss') }
```

Comment: Hmm. When I try this, I still get the error that the property does not exist.

Comment: @Shane with the xml provided in question this code works just fine for me updating all values of the `start` property of each object

Comment: Working now. Not sure what changed, but I really appreciate your help. Thank you!